# pytest - using patch as a decorator to patch a constant

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, decorator, patch

I have an object `MyObject` which uses a constant defined in `mymodule.constants.MYCONSTANT`. I can successfully patch the constant using a context manger like so:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_constant(self):
    with patch('mymodule.constants.MYCONSTANT', 3):
        MyObject()
```

However, I can't figure out how to use the equivalent patching using `patch` as a decorator:

```
@patch('mymodule.constants.MYCONSTANT', 3)
def test_constant(self, mock_constant):
     MyObject()
```

The above fails with a `fixture mock_constant not found` error. I tried using

```
@patch('mymodule.constants.MYCONSTANT', return_value=3)
```

But `MYCONSTANT` doesn't get replaced with the value of 3.

Comment: If you provide a replacement value in the decorator, no argument is inserted into the test function, so if you remove the `mock_constant` argument in your example, it may work. `return_value` works only for the result of a function call or class instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is aligned to the behavior as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

> **`unittest.mock.patch(target, new=DEFAULT, spec=None, create=False, spec_set=None, autospec=None, new_callable=None, **kwargs)`**
>
> ... If `patch()` is used as a decorator and new is omitted, the created mock is passed in as an extra argument to the decorated function.

So, if you want to pass the extra argument to the decorated function, don't set the `new` argument:

```
@patch('mymodule.constants.MYCONSTANT')
def test_constant(self, mock_constant):
    ...
```

Setting the `new` argument means no extra argument would be passed:

```
@patch('mymodule.constants.MYCONSTANT', 3)
def test_constant(self):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Guys the order of parameters matter so **first mocks** then **fixtures**, otherwise it will still throw you the same error.

```
@patch('server.app.UserValidator')
def test_first_mocks(self,mock_user_validator:MagicMock,client_fixture:FlaskClient):
    # Arrange
    input = {'password':'internal','username':'error'}
    mock_user_validator.side_effect = ValueError('testing')
    # Act
    response = client_fixture.post('/api/users',json=input)
    # Assert
    mock_user_validator.assert_called_once()
    assert response.status_code == 500
```